# issue_comment is running in the background but I want to run it on the pull request page

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to listen to an edited comment and the GitHub actions to choose block merge or available merge.
So it is working on the actions tab but isn’t seen on the pull request screen.
How can I add GitHub action when comments to edited in the pull request screen?

Thank You

```yaml
name: xx
run-name: xx
on: [issue_comment]
jobs:
  xx:
  ...
```

Now:
[image: Screen Shot 2022-10-14 at 13 50 11]
[image: Screen Shot 2022-10-14 at 13 51 03]
Expected:
[image]

Comment: Did you add a branch protection [requiring status checks before merging](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#require-status-checks-before-merging)?

Comment: I tried to post-commit status with GitHub actions on every comment edit. It's like it's working. Thank you. @GuiFalourd